# Print sheet names from googlesheets

Tags: r, excel, google-sheets, googlesheets4

Brand new to googlesheets4. I have an Excel workbook here:

```
library(googlesheets4)
read_sheet("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RBtzn3_FXxz1YD4McQJ29pU-UUodKMVM182-Bmx2Xas/edit?usp=sharing")
```

This workbook has 3 sheets. My question is: what googlesheets4 function do I use to see the names of the sheets within the book? I was reading about gs4_example but couldn't figure out how to use it.
I am basically trying to use something similar to this:

```
gs4_get(gs4_example("mini-gap"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sheet_names` function.

```
sheet_names("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RBtzn3_FXxz1YD4McQJ29pU-UUodKMVM182-Bmx2Xas/edit?usp=sharing")
# [1] "RBsalmon"    "RBtrout"     "RBsteelhead"
```

I found this quickly by opening the index of all `googlesheets4` functions in my RStudio help window and then using the find feature on the word "name".

Comment: Thank you much @Gregor Thomas. I am going to start reading more about this package.